# How to extract an n size window substring from any string?

Tags: python, list, loops, slice

Given a list of elements, how to create a window of an arbitrary size, and extract n elements to the left and right from the center? For example, given:

```
l = ['This', 'document', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'document']
```

and a window = 2

How to extract the following sublist:

```
['document', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'document']
```

So far I tried to:

```
middle = int((len(l)/2))

middle_element = l[middle]
middle_index = l.index(l[middle])

left_side = l[:middle_index]
right_side = l[middle_index:]
sublist = left_side+right_side
```

The problem with my approach is that it doesnt work for any list of any size. How should I control sliding from the left and right once I find the center of the list?

Comment: Sorry, it was not clear to me. Is `['document', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'document']` the desired output you want to get, or the output you're currently facing?

Comment: With a `window=2`, do you want to transform this list `['This', 'document', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'document']`, into this other list `['document', 'is', 'the', 'second']`?

Comment: Need more info.  The sample is length 6.  the middle is *between* `is` and `the` and two to the left/right would be `['document','is','the','second']`.  How do you want to handle odd/even list length?  Give more examples to clarify.  Make a [mcve] with your full attempt to compute the middle and extract elements so we can correct.

Comment: @CarlHR yes, that is the desired output. The output I am getting is wrong. Yes with a window size 2 I would like to get that other list

Comment: @MarkTolonen I added how to calculate the middle of the list. I forgot to do it, the problem now is how given the middle, go to the left and right for any window size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do what your question asks:

```py
l = ['This', 'document', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'document']
window = 2
middle = int((len(l)/2))
sublist = l[max(0, middle - window):min(len(l), middle + window + 1)]
```

Output:

```
['document', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'document']
```

Explanation:

We take a slice of `l` starting at `middle - window` (but no less than 0 as enforced using `max()`). Ignoring edge cases, this ensures we get `middle - window`, `middle - window + 1`, ..., `middle - window + window` which are a total of `window + 1` list items (numbering `window` items to the left of `middle` in addition to the item at index `middle`). Our slice ends at `middle + window + 1` (guarded against going out of range by `min()`, though technically this is not required as slices are forgiving of end-of-range values greater than the sequence length) which, in addition to the items already accounted for above, adds the items `middle + 1`, ..., `middle + window` (but not the item `middle + window + 1` as slice notation does not include the end of the slice range) which count for an additional `window` items to the right of the the `middle` index.

Comment: I added how to calculate `middle`

Comment: Updated to reflect OP's clarification of how to calculate `middle`.

Comment: Could you add an explanation?

Comment: Answer updated with detailed explanation.

Comment: @Carl HR I agree that `int((len(l)/2)` gives the same result as `len(l) // 2` (and it also has an unnecessary level of parentheses). However, I'm not sure what is meant by your comment referencing what must be considered in calculating `middle`; I'm just taking OP's stated policy as a specification stipulated by the question.